# Inverse FFT in C#

Tags: c#, fft, ifft

I am writing an application for procedural audiofiles, I have to analyze my new file, get its frequency spectrum and change it in its calculated.

I want to do this with the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT). This is my recursive C# FFT:

```
void ft(float n, ref Complex[] f)
{
    if (n > 1)
    {
        Complex[] g = new Complex[(int) n / 2];
        Complex[] u = new Complex[(int) n / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
        {
            g[i] = f[i * 2];
            u[i] = f[i * 2 + 1];
        }

        ft(n / 2, ref g);
        ft(n / 2, ref u);

        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
        {
            float a = i;
            a = -2.0f * Mathf.PI * a / n;
            float cos = Mathf.Cos(a);
            float sin = Mathf.Sin(a);
            Complex c1 = new Complex(cos, sin);
            c1 = Complex.Multiply(u[i], c1);
            f[i] = Complex.Add(g[i], c1);

            f[i + (int) n / 2] = Complex.Subtract(g[i], c1);
        }
    }
}
```

The inspiring example was [image: from wiki]

I then compared my results with those from [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier%280.6%2C0.7%2C0.8%2C0.9%29) for the same input `0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9` but the results aren't be the same. My results are twice as big than Wolfram's and the imaginary part are the -2 times of Wolfram's.

Also, wiki indicates that the inverse of FFT can be computed with

[image: this]

But I compare inputs and outputs and they are different.

Has anyone an idea what's wrong?

Comment: Find existing library that deals with FFT. Not really sure what you expect to gain from someone else debugging your code for you.

Comment: I want somebody with experience of fft, how can explain me how to get the inverse of fft for example use a other algorithm or perhaps it is not possible. My code work. I try it with a sinus and cosinus input and get the right output.

Answer (score 4):

Different implementations often use different definitions of the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT), with correspondingly different results. The correspondence between implementations is usually fairly trivial (such as a scaling factor).

More specifically, your implementation is based on the following definition of the DFT:

[image: OP's DFT definition]

On the other hand, Wolfram alpha by default uses [a definition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FourierTransforms.html#30397), which after adjusting to 0-based indexing looks like:

[image: Wolfram alpha default DFT definition]

Correspondingly, it is possible to transform the result of your implementation to match Wolfram alpha's with:

```
void toWolframAlphaDefinition(ref Complex[] f)
{
  float scaling = (float)(1.0/Math.Sqrt(f.Length));
  for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++)
  {
    f[i] = scaling * Complex.Conjugate(f[i]);
  }
}
```

Now as far as computing the inverse DFT using the forward transform, a direct implementation of the formula

[image: OP's inverse formula]

you provided would be:

```
void inverseFt(ref Complex[] f)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++)
  {
    f[i] = Complex.Conjugate(f[i]);
  }
  ft(f.Length, ref f);
  float scaling = (float)(1.0 / f.Length);
  for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++)
  {
    f[i] = scaling * Complex.Conjugate(f[i]);
  }
}
```

Calling `ft` on the original sequence `0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9` should thus get you the transformed sequence `3, -0.2+0.2j, -0.2, -0.2-0.2j`.

Further calling `inverseFt` on this transform sequence should then bring you back to your original sequence `0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9` (within some reasonable floating point error), as shown in [this live demo](https://ideone.com/SheAor).

Comment: So does this inverse function only apply for the wolfram definition ? If so what would the function be for the first DFT definition ?

Comment: @WDUK `inverseFt` applies to the OP's original `ft` implementation (and corresponding definition of the DFT), as per the `ideone` demo.